# "in Process" Ran out of gas

Tags: out-of-gas

Kyrptono Exchange Customer Support has refused to respond to my problem.  The transaction failed, because it ran out of gas,  I can still see a shadow of my DGX on Kyrptono account, but after 7 months it still reads "in-process"  Is there any way to recover these coins, or is it a total loss?  I did add some ETH to my account.  Could I throw some more gas at it to force the transaction?

Transaction Hash: 0x4f05f8801ff6e28953b18987200436f2a0c6c41642366d75a9c6cea82e793a47

Comment: The statements "The transaction failed, because it ran out of gas" and "it still reads in-process" does not match. It's likely that the latter is an issue with the frontend.

Comment: It reads "in process" on my Kryptono account.  It also shows the amount of DGX tokens that I had but shows 0 available.